# Deploy Angularjs app as a standalone Desktop application manner

Tags: angularjs, rest, deployment, desktop-application

Is there any possibility to deploy the Angularjs app as a standalone Desktop application manner?. 
This Angularjs application behave as a REST client which communicate with Spring REST back end Server.

Comment: I've never used it, but I guess http://electron.atom.io/ could be the solution.

Comment: I never used it either, they have good show cases, so I trust it is working fine. Chrome app would be another solution, but at least in osx it is bound to the browser, so I cannot separate the application from chrome properly (see google hangout).